# Drupal 8 Forms/Webforms Ajax Callback Elements

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

I'm looking to add/edit elements on a Drupal 8 webform with Ajax Callbacks, I've read up on the buildForm technique, however my problem is a little more complicated, in that I am actually trying to do all of this inside of a custom composite element, not a form object.

Adding a new element via HtmlCommand is no problem, however any '#ajax' callbacks I add to this new element do not get initialised.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add elements in an ajax callback:

> Note, that as part of the Form APIs security system, you **cannot**
>   create new form elements in the callback function, as they will throw
>   errors upon submission, and any #ajax on elements created in the
>   callback will also not work. If you need to create new elements on
>   ajax submit, they must be added in the form definition.

from https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms-in-drupal-7 (still valid for D8).

It should be possible to find a method in the composite element which is part of the form building process where you can add the form element.

Comment: Yup, I've tried several functions like **processWebformComposite** but the **form_state is never correct**, I have even tried to use hooks, but I never receive the correct **form_state** (rebuild is always false and manually added rebuild info array is empty)